# How to overwrite the implementation of a method when testing an Angular service with Jest?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, spy

EDIT:

It turns out the problem was not the part of the code I presented here, but the one I ommitted. I don't delete the question just in case someone finds the example and the answer useful.

---

I need to test an Angular service with Jest. The `GameService` has a `start` method which calls a `manage` method. In order to test `start` I need just to spy on `manage` to check that it is called, but avoid its actual execution.

The `jest.spyOn()` method by itself doesn't overwrite the original implementation of a method. One needs to provide that implementation oneself. The docs suggest two ways of doing this:

- `jest.spyOn(gameService, 'manage').mockImplementation(() => {});`
- `gameService.manage = jest.fn(() => {});`

However, although both alternatives allow me to spy on the calls of `manage`, they don't avoid the execution of the actual `manage` method.

This seems to be [a recurrent problem](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6972), but I haven't found a solution that works for me. I just want to know if someone has experienced a similar issue in Angular and could find a solution.

The code of my service and its spec is the following (I will omit irrelevant test cases):

**game.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { OneDeviceModule } from '../one-device.module';
import { PlayersService } from './players.service';
import { Player } from '../../models/player';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: OneDeviceModule
})
export class GameService {
  public players: Player[];

  constructor(private playersService: PlayersService) { }

  public start(): void {
    const players = this.playersService.getPlayersList();
    if (players.length < 2) {
      throw new Error('There must be at least two players to start the game');
    }
    this.players = players;
    this.manage();
  }

  public manage(): void {
    while(this.goesOn()) {

    }
  }

  public goesOn(): boolean {
    return true;
  }
}
```

**game.service.spec.ts**

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';
import { GameService } from './game.service';
import { PlayersService } from './players.service';
import { Player } from '../../models/player';

jest.mock('./players.service');
const mockedPlayersService = mocked(PlayersService, true);

const players = [
  new Player('John'),
  new Player('Anna'),
  new Player('Julia')
];

describe('GameService', () => {
  let gameService: GameService;
  let playersService: PlayersService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ providers: [GameService, PlayersService]});
    gameService = TestBed.inject(GameService);
    playersService = mockedPlayersService.mock.instances[0];
    (playersService.getPlayersList as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue(players);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    mockedPlayersService.mockClear();
    (playersService.getPlayersList as jest.Mock).mockClear();
  });
  
  describe('constructor', () => {
    ...
  });

  describe('start', () => {    
    function onePlayerSetup(playersService: PlayersService): void {
      (playersService.getPlayersList as jest.Mock).mockClear();
      (playersService.getPlayersList as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue([new Player('John')]);
    }
    const mockManage: jest.Mock<void, never[]> = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {});

    ...

    it('should not call manage method if there are less than 2 players', () => {
      onePlayerSetup(playersService);
      gameService.manage = mockManage;
      try { gameService.start(); }
      catch { }
      finally { expect(mockManage).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0); }
    });

    it('should call manage method if everything is ok', () => {
      gameService.manage = mockManage;
      gameService.start();
      expect(mockManage).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

While I have never worked with `ts-jest/utils/mocked`, I would use Angular's Dependency Injection to make sure the mocked service gets used instead of the original one, as it is a perfect tool for this job:

```
  let gameService: GameService;
  let playersService: PlayersService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    playersService = // prepare your mock
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ providers: [
      GameService,
      { provide: PlayersService, useValue: playersService } // inject your mock
    ]});
    gameService = TestBed.inject(GameService);
    // ...
  });
```

You could then even provide a simpler version of the playersService:

```
  let gameService: GameService;
  let playersService = { getPlayersList: () => [] };
  
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ providers: [
      GameService,
      { provide: PlayersService, useValue: playersService } // inject your mock
    ]});
    gameService = TestBed.inject(GameService);
  });
  
  it('should not call manage method if there are less than 2 players', () => {
    playersService.getPlayersList = () => [new Player('John')];
    expect(gameService.start()).toThrow();
  });
```

Comment: That's a good alternative to mock another dependency, but that's not what's wrong with my tests, since the dependency is mocked correctly. My issue is how to mock other methods within the dependency I am testing.